# I received a crash log from App Review,when i submitted my App. There are some difficulties when I get fully symbolicated crash log

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When I submitted my App I received crash reports from App Review.I tried to get fully symbolicated by `Xcode`, `symbolicatecrash` , `atos`      . Then I get same result:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001873e6014 0x1873c7000 + 126996     
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001874ad460 0x1874a8000 + 21600    
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018735a3f4 0x1872f7000 + 406516      
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000186e252d4 0x186e24000 + 4820    
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000186e3f688 0x186e24000 + 112264    
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000186e3f234 0x186e24000 + 111156    
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000186e5071c 0x186e48000 + 34588
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001882f20bc 0x1882e9000 + 37052
8   UIKit                           0x000000018e2c47cc 0x18e24a000 + 501708
9   UIKit                           0x000000018e2bf550 0x18e24a000 + 480592
10  Family Health Tracker           0x0000000100142e60 main (main.m:16)
11  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001872d45b8 0x1872d0000 + 17848
```

I still can't get fully symbolicated crash log. I still don't know how to shoot my crash or reproduce the crash. and you can also tell me how to get fully symbolicated log. Very thx.

Comment: Are you using any analytics tools like fabric(crashlytics) in your project?

Comment: Crashlytics is a free service offered by Twitter that collects your crashes and various other bits of information

Comment: If it was already included in your project it will be easy for you to get information about the crash

Comment: some Ui related changes made in background queue need to make a ui related changes on main queue.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is crashing randomly then you need to analyze your code. That you can do in XCode only.Open your Project in XCode and in Product menu you will find the Analyze option (cmd+shift+B) make sure you have selected "iOS Device" before analyzing it.

other than this you can use the this link:

[Instruments Tutorial with Swift: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode)

apple will not accept your app if it is crashing.

or you can test your app using [crashlytics](https://fabric.io/login?redirect_url=%2Fhome)